# Finding a composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give a composition series for the following modules (where the action in each case is the usual
matrix multiplication):

a) $\Bbbk_n$ as an $M_n(\Bbbk)$-module

b) $\Bbbk_n$ as a $T_n(\Bbbk)$-module

I know M is a square matrix and T is the upper triangle matrix but I have no idea how to use this generalisation to find a composition series for these

Comment: Sorry i misworded what i was trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're operating on the right of $\mathbb k^n$ with matrices.

Hints:

1. $\mathbb k^n$ is a simple $M_n(\mathbb k)$ module.
2. Start out with $T_2(\mathbb k)$ and check if $\{0\}\times \mathbb k$ is a submodule of $\mathbb k^n$. If it is, dimensionality would say that you can't have a smaller submodule. The same can be said about $(\mathbb k\times\mathbb k)/(\{0\}\times \mathbb k)$.  See how this generalizes to $\mathbb k^3$ and beyond.

Comment: So for part 1 would it be correct to say the only submodules are the trivial submodules 0 and kn?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on 2? I'm struggling to understand what you're saying sorry

Comment: @johnsmith Yes, for part 1, the composition series is as simple as possible.  But you'd have to prove that it is simple.

Comment: @johnsmith My advice for 2) is just to work it out for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and you will probably notice a pattern.

Comment: what does {0} represent, a matrix with all entries as 0? I assume not because then multiplying it by k is pointless

Comment: @johnsmith it represents the set with a single element $0$.